# Best way to insert high-frequency data in InfluxDB

Tags: python, database, http, influxdb, timeserieschart

I am storing high-frequency data from sensors. I would like to be able to store them using Influx.

I am reading this data (only available in CSV files) using Pandas (Python script), and making http requests in order to send batches (10000 records) to Influx Server.

Let's say that I have 1M records per minute: I am absolutely not able to replicate this speed using my script (even subtracting time needed for CSV file opening and reading).

How can I speed things up? Data coming from sensors will never stop, I need to keep up with it.

Comment: What you describe looks like pretty common problem succesfully solved many times with numerous tools. The answer to `how can I speed things up?` is `write some right code to eliminate bottlenecks`. I mean no chance to help you without your code and explanation.